# How to get SBT to write cucumber reports in module target folder

Tags: sbt, cucumber

I have a multi-module SBT project and I have added some cucumber feature files.

I want the html reports written to the module's target folder

```
private val cucumberTestOptions = Seq(Tests.Argument(cucumberFramework, "--plugin", s"html:${moduleName.key}/target/html"))
```

But I can't see how to get the module name to evaluate.  This writes the file to literally .../moduleName/target/html